# System API design approach

Tags: rest, api, mule, uri, raml

I want to design System API which is going to connect with REST service using RAML for Healthcare domain.
Backend Rest service will have GET/POST requests.
GET/POST request will usually serve getCollection/getById/getByName.

How can I start approaching designing RAML?
Which is the best and standard way to do it?
anyone can help me with the below items.
The naming convention used to name for Process/System/Experience API's.
URI design
any other architectural suggestions if you want to add.

Thanks,
Vijay D

Answer (score 0):

Regarding RAML I would suggest below tutorials are very useful and are well explained with exmaples

```
https://raml.org/developers/raml-100-tutorial
https://raml.org/developers/raml-200-tutorial
```

You can also look at raml spec at below url

```
https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md
```

Regarding naming convention and design. These are quite broad topics. I would suggest below book which is available from mulesoft to download is a good place to start.

```
https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/ebook/api/restbook
```

Also Here is the link to ebook resources and on bottom you can see all resources section which can help you with different areas you looking to explore.

```
https://www.mulesoft.com/ebook
```